# [PHP]native method to convert an unsigned integer to a binary string (not textual binary string)

Tags: php

Is there any native method that converts an unsigned integer to a binary string (either big-endian order or little-endian order is okay). The current way I come up with is:

```
$n = 0x12345678;
$s = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    //For big-endian: $s[$i] = chr(($n >> 8 * (4 - 1 - $i)) & 0xff);
    $s[$i] = chr(($n >> 8 * $i) & 0xff);
}
```

But these are not performant, I wonder if there is some native method that does the job. But I haven't found any for now.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php

Comment: decbin is not the right method, it converts an integer to a textual binary string. I mean an actual binary string, not a textual binary string (See the title of the question).

Comment: Unbale to understand the difference between _actual binary string_  and _textual binary string_

Comment: Understand and run my code, and then `var_dump($s)`. And then run `var_dump(decbin($n));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I found two ways to achieve this:

The better of the two slutions, that I am going to use:

```
$n = 0x12345678;
//For big-endian: var_dump(pack('N', $n));
var_dump(pack('V', $n));
```

and suboptimally:

```
$n = 0x12345678;
//This only supports big-endian.
var_dump(hex2bin(dechex($n)));
```